# String to char array in c++

Tags: c++

I was making a simple program in c++ to convert a string to a char array and then print it out. My code is:

```
string UserImput;
int lenght;

 
 void Test()
{
     getline(cin, UserImput);
     
     lenght = UserImput.size();

     char char_array[lenght + 1];
     copy(UserImput.begin(), UserImput.end(), char_array);

    
     cout << char_array;
   
}
```

The error I am getting is "expression must have a costant value" and I do not know why.

Comment: variable length arrays are not allowed in c++. The size of an array must be known at compile time, you aren't allowed to calculate it from run-time input.

Comment: Or you need to use new/delete to create your runtime sized buffer.  You will also need to add a NUL terminator to your char array to print it correctly after your copy, unless you print it manually 1 character at a time.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? `std::string`s already use arrays under the hood. Use `.c_str()` go get the pointer to its first element (or `.data()` for a writeable pointer).

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are optionally allowed in C programs and by by extension by some C++ compilers, notably g++, so don't be surprised when you see them in examples and tutorials. Just don't expect the example to work under your compiler.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @Jozese Also note that `new[]` does not zero memory, and a `std::string`'s iterators do not include a null-terminator, so even though your `char_array` is allocating space for a null-terminator, it will not actually contain a null-terminator, so `cout << char_array;` will likely run past the end of the allocated memory. So, you will need to add `char_array[lenght] = '\0';` after the `copy()`.  Or, just don't use a `char[]` array to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

In `char char_array[lenght + 1];`, `lenght + 1` is not a compile-time constant. The size of an array must be known at compile-time.  Since the value of `length` is not known until runtime, you will need to allocate memory dynamically in this situation. For example:

`char* char_array = new char[lenght + 1];`

Don't forget to delete the array when you are done:

`delete[] char_array;`

Comment: Rather than using `new[]` directly, you should use `std::vector` instead, then you don't have to worry about calling `new[]`/`delete[]` manually, eg: `std::vector<char> char_array(lenght + 1); std::copy(UserImput.begin(), UserImput.end(), char_array.begin()); std::cout << char_array.data();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  char* c = _strdup(UserImput.c_str());
```

But I wonder - why? Just to output it to `cout`? Then you can do:

```
cout << UserImput.c_str();
```

Comment: Or better, `cout << UserImput;` since `operator<<` has an overload for `std::string`

Comment: Side note: Remember that the buffer returned by `strdup` needs to be `free`ed, not `delete`ed.